# How to use Spark Streaming from an other vm with kafka

Tags: apache-spark, virtual-machine, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I have Spark Streaming on a virtual machine, and I would like to connect it with an other vm which contains kafka . I want Spark to get the data from the kafka machine.
Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is definitely possible. In fact, this is the reason why we have distributed systems in place :)

When writing your Spark Streaming program, if you are using Kafka, you will have to create a Kafka config data structure (syntax will vary depending on your programming language and client). In that config structure, you will have to specify the Kafka brokers IP. This would be the IP of your Kafka VM.

You then just need to run Spark Streaming Application on your Spark VM.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, when I launch spark-submit on my spark vm, I often get the error "Unable to connect to zookeeper server within timeout: 10000", do you know what may cause that ? I think the ip adress I used is ok.

Comment: Well, I don't which client or language you are using, so can't comment on the exact solution. Most likely though, you need to specify broker IPs in the Spark Application and not zookeeper (again check the API doc clearly)...
If zookeeper is a problem, I believe you should isolate it by just using Kafka alone and try to produce-consume messages using kafka scripts. This would help you narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible and makes perfect sense to have them on separate VM's. That way there is a clear separation of roles.